# Angular 6 multiple @input() level

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component that contain multiple level of children components :

```
Parent
  |
Child1
  |
Child2
  |
Child3
```

I'm trying to pass a value from parent to each children through `@Input()`

So for example in the parent I have this :

```
@Input() info: Info= {} as Info;
```

It is initialized in `ngOnInit` of the parent component and the value is OK, I checked it.

In the Template I set :

```
[info]="info"
```

Each child have the same input as the parent.

The value is correclty passed to the `Child1` but from the `Child2` to `Child3` the value stay empty, how is that ?

Comment: IS child 2 a child component of Child 1 and child 3 a chld component of child 2?

Comment: as @SiddAjmera mentioned, according to your diagram, child 2 is basically the child of child 1 and grandchild of parent.. is that correct?

Comment: SharedService is the perfect solution for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't pass an `@Input` property to the Child of a Child Component from the `ParentCompoennt`. To do that, you have two ways:

1. Pass the `@Input` from Child 1 to Child 2 in Child 1's template.
2. Create a SharedService which will be injected as a dependency in Parent, Child1, Child2 and Child3. From the Parent, set that property and then get that property in Child1, Child2, and Child 3.

I'd recommend using the SharedService approch.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
export class SharedService {
  private input: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public input$: Observable<any> = this.resultList.asObservable();

  setInput(input) {
    this.input.next(input);
  }
}
```

And then in all the Child Components:

```
input: any;
...
constructor(private sharedService : SharedService ) {}
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedService.input$.subscribe(input => this.input = input);
}
```