# Best way to pass object between siblings Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm looking to understand what is the best way to pass the user object resulted from my login to other components.

```
 login() {
this.http.post<Usuario>(this.baseUrl, {
  username: this.usuario.username,
  clave: this.usuario.clave
}).subscribe(data => {
  if (data != null) {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
    localStorage.setItem('token', btoa(this.usuario.username + ':' + this.usuario.clave));
    this.router.navigate(['/buscador']);
    this.usuario2 = data;
    console.log(this.usuario2);

  } else {
    alert('Authentication failed.');
  }
});}
```

This is my login method in my login component, if the validation is correct since the service i'm consuming returns an user object, I store the user object into "usuario2", what I would want to know is the best way for other components to have access to this variable.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992325/2622292) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best development pattern here would be to create `LoginService`, a service which contains all of the logic for authentication/local storage (https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services).  There are a lot of reasons why the services pattern is beneficial;

1. It gives you a clean interface to all of the functionality you are extending; so if you decide to change the implementation later, you can do this without hunting down all of the callsites.
2. Similarly, you can easily swap the implementation at runtime so that you can mock the service.  For instance, you could create `MockLoginService` which you use when in non-production mode, which prints debugging data and hits a local as opposed to production server.
3. You can use dependency injection, so it is easily accessible in any given module.

Comment: It is also often useful in cases like this to use a BehaviorSubject to store the data in the service, and expose this publicly as an Observable so that it can be subscribed to for changes.

Comment: @Mike absolutely- that way you can pass it directly into the `async` pipe!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what you mean is that I should do the logic in the service and then use dependency injection to access the value of the user?

Comment: I made it work using the shared service as you propose, Thanks!, but do you know how could I also make the parent aware of changes in the "usuario2" object?, I'm looking to find a way for the navbar to go away once the user logs in.

Comment: @FlavioAlarcon as Mike said- create an `isLoggedIn()` method which returns a boolean observable.  Then just add `*ngIf="userService.isLoggedIn() | async` to your navbar.

Comment: @DerekBrown I tried your suggestion and I get "Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'" error.

Comment: @DerekBrown nevermind I made a mistake it's working now, what I get now is an error called ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, after some research I understand why it's there but not how to fix it,also appareantly it only happens while in development so idk if I should bother.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the lines of

```
# Simple passing of data between components using a dedicated data service

export class LoginService {

  username: string;

  getUsername(): string {
    return this.username;
  }

  setUserName(username: string) {
    this.username = username
  }

}

# Using a behavior subject so other active components are updated with the new value whenever it changes.

export class LoginService {

  username: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");;

  watchUsername(): BehaviorSubject<string> {
    return this.username;
  }

  setUserName(username: string) {
    this.username.next(username);
  }

}

# You can then consume the Behavior subject like this

this.loginService.watchUserName.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```